# Argument ignored in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I tried to create an array with several elements in Powershell. One of the elements should be a comma-delimited String consisting of the elements of another array. I tried using this code:

```
$list = @("a","b")
$result =  @("1 " + $list -join ",", "2")
```

I expected `$result` to be an array consisting of two elements: `1 a,b` and `2`. But actually, it is an array consisting of the single element `1 a b`.

This problem can be solved by adding parantheses like this:

```
$result = @(("1 " + $list -join ","), "2")
```

Looking at [Powershell Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operator_precedence?view=powershell-6), the `,` seems to have precedence over the concatenation, so these two lines are identically regarding precedence

```
$result =  @("1 " + $list -join ",", "2")
$result =  @("1 " + $list -join (",", "2"))
```

So obviously, the `join` operator receives a list of Strings as its argument. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-6), `join` only takes one argument.

My questions are:

*What does `join`do with this argument? And why doesn't it throw an error?*

Comment: `[string] (",", "2")` -> `, 2`. Why does converting an array to a string produce a space-separated version of its elements? Um, it just does. As a scripting language, PowerShell generally isn't big on producing errors if it can also do something vaguely useful instead. So what you get is effectively `("1 " + $list) -join ", 2"`, which, being a `join` of just one element, gives the input (`"1 " + [string] $list`), which as mentioned reduces to `"1 a b"`.

Comment: To actually get what you're after, you need `@(("1 " + ($list -join ",")), "2")`. Looks over-parenthesized, but it's not.

Comment: Also, the reason `[string]$list` is a space-separated string is because that is the default behavior. The `$OFS` automatic variable controls that setting. Setting `$OFS = ';'` will result in semi-colon delimited string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array passed to -join operator on the right side is coerced into a string.  I didn't realize you could do it.

```
[string](1,2)
1 2

'a','a' -join 4,5,6
a4 5 6a
```

I'm not sure why the behavior with cmdlet arguments is different.  The -filter parameter is type string.

```
get-childitem -filter *.txt,*.ps1
Get-ChildItem : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Filter'. Specified method is not supported.
```

The array becomes a string in this example:

```
& { param([string]$a) $a } 1,2,3
1 2 3
```

By the way, it's a myth that @( ) is needed to create arrays. The comma operator is enough.

```
$list = 'a','b'
$result = ('1 ' + $list -join ','),'2' 
$result
1 a b
2
```